# $n $ balls and $n$ bins

Tags: probability

Suppose that $n$ balls are thrown independently and uniformly at random
into $n$ bins.

EDIT: Sorry, i write wrong question

Correct is: Find the conditional probability that bin $i$ has one ball given that exactly one ball fell into the first three bins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach: let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the number of balls in bins 1 and 2 respectively. Then
$$P(X_1 < X_2) + P(X_1 > X_2) + P(X_1 = X_2) = 1.$$
By symmetry, $P(X_1 < X_2) = P(X_1 > X_2)$, so we have
$$P(X_1 > X_2) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - P(X_1 = X_2)).$$
Now compute $P(X_1 = X_2)$.
It may help to write it as $$P(X_1 = X_2) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} P(X_1 = X_2 = k).$$

> \begin{align}P(X_1 = X_2 = k) &= P(\text{$k$ balls in bin 1, $k$ balls in bin 2, $n-2k$ balls in other bins})\\ &= \left(\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\right)^2 \left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^{n-2k}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
But I have no idea how can I solve this sum :/ Can you give some hints?